# Fix chunklist URLs inside m3u8 file

Tags: streaming, http-live-streaming, wowza

I have an apple HLS streaming using wowza ...

What I want to do is to fix the chunklist URLs inside the m3u8 file every time that the player GETs the `master m3u8`...
For example this is the first data that first time I get :

```
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-VERSION:3 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=405000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=360x240 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w1230758641_b374000.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1052672,CODECS="avc1.66.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w1230758641_b1052672.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=834000,CODECS="avc1.66.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w1230758641_b764000.m3u8
```

and this is the second one:

```
: #EXTM3U #EXT-X-VERSION:3 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=405000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=360x240 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w591669537_b374000.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1052672,CODECS="avc1.66.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w591669537_b1052672.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=834000,CODECS="avc1.66.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480 http://*:1935/sportplus4/_definst_/ngrp:plus4_all/chunklist_w591669537_b764000.m3u8
```

I don't want the chunklist_w**** to change every time ... I saw some other `m3u8s` that are fixed like this one :

```
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change in WOWZA, but I just check I can EDIT the URLs replacing the number with "X"s:

chunklist_w591669537_b374000.m3u8 --> chunklist_wXXXXXXXXXX_b374000.m3u8

and it works.